# How to get return value from PG/SQL function using npgsql

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

Using the npgsql module with Microsoft .Net, how do I get the return value of a PostgreSQL function?  Not the value of a named parameter, or a ref cursor, but a RETURNed single string/number value?

thanks!

Martin

Comment: Note that PostgreSQL functions can't be "executed" like stored procedures in MySQL or SQLServer. A function in PostgreSQL must always be selected, e.g. `select myfunction('foo', 'bar')`

Answer (score 0):

So, I had a PL/pgSQL function declared as follows (I am using EnterpriseDB [version 9.5], I am not sure this would be valid in vanilla PostgreSQL):

```
FUNCTION f_auth_user (p_user_name           IN     VARCHAR2,
                     p_user_pwd            IN     VARCHAR2,
                     p_security_user_seq      OUT NUMBER,
                     p_login_key              OUT VARCHAR2,
                     p_psn_id                 OUT NUMBER,
                     p_message                OUT VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER;
```

The dotNet code that called it looked like this:

```
            EDBCommand cmd = new EDBCommand("smcs.pkg_login.f_auth_user(:p_user_name, :p_user_pwd, :p_security_user_seq, :p_login_key, :p_psn_id, :p_message)", conn); 
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_return_value", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Integer, 256).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_user_name", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Varchar2, 256).Value = txtUserName.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_user_pwd", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Varchar2, 256).Value = txtPassword.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_security_user_seq", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Integer, 256).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_login_key", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Varchar2, 256).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_psn_id", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Integer, 256).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_message", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Varchar2, 256).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

This general approach worked with Oracle, but it appears that I need to move the code adding the parameter for the return value to the end of the parameter list, so my working code is like this:

```
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_user_name", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Varchar2, 256).Value = txtUserName.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_user_pwd", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Varchar2, 256).Value = txtPassword.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_security_user_seq", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Integer, 256).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_login_key", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Varchar2, 256).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_psn_id", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Integer, 256).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_message", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Varchar2, 256).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            returnParam = new EDBParameter("p_return_value", EDBTypes.EDBDbType.Integer);
            returnParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(returnParam);
```

It is very likely that I could have condensed the creation and use of the p_return_value parameter into 2 or 1 statements, I haven't tried that yet.

I can then execute and retrieve results (including the return value) like this:

```
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sequence = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["p_security_user_seq"].Value.ToString());
            loginKey = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["p_login_key"].Value.ToString());
            message = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["p_message"].Value.ToString());
            authenticatedUser = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters["p_return_value"].Value.ToString());
            conn.Close();
```

Thanks!

Martin